# Inverse function of $x^2-4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The function $h$ is defined by $$h(x)=x^2-4$$. for $$x\leq0$$

Find an expression for $h^{-1}(x)$

My attempt,

Let $h^{-1}(x)=a$

$x=h(a)$

$x=a^2-4$

$a=\sqrt{x+4}$

$h^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{x+4}$

Am I wrong? Is the answer $-\sqrt{x+4}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other answers have already correctly addressed it, but just for the sake of having another point of view, here's how I'd run through an example when I used to teach it.

We're given:
$$ h(x) = x^2 - 4, \qquad x \le 0 $$

Replace $h(x)$ with $y$:
$$ y = x^2 - 4, \qquad x \le 0 $$

Swap all $x$ and $y$, *including in the restriction*:
$$ x = y^2 - 4, \qquad y \le 0 $$

Notice now we have $y \le 0$ since we swapped $x$ and $y$ in the restriction!

The next step is to solve for $y$ in the equation:
\begin{align}
  x &= y^2 - 4\\
  x+4 &= y^2\\
  \sqrt{x+4} &= \sqrt{y^2}\\
  \sqrt{x+4} &= |y|\\
  \pm \sqrt{x+4} &= y
\end{align}

As others have pointed out, we must be careful and remember that $\sqrt{y^2} = |y|$ in general.  The very last equality above, i.e., $y = \pm\sqrt{x+4}$, follows from the definition of absolute value.

So now the question is, which root do we take?  The positive or negative root?  Well, remember our restriction earlier.  It says $y \le 0$.  Therefore we must take the negative root:  $y = -\sqrt{x+4}$.  So we have:
$$ y = -\sqrt{x+4}, \qquad y \le 0 $$

Finally, replace $y$ with $h^{-1}(x)$ to get the final result:
$$h^{-1}(x) = -\sqrt{x+4}, \qquad h^{-1}(x) \le 0$$

Notice how the domain of $h(x)$ and range of $h^{-1}(x)$ are the same, as we would expect.  They're both  $(-\infty, 0]$ in interval notation.

Answer (score 3):

There is a misstep in your procedure.

$y = x^2 - 4 \implies x^2 = y + 4\implies \sqrt{x^2} = \sqrt{y+4}$

Note that $\sqrt x^2 = x$ but $\sqrt{x^2} \neq x$ in general. Actually, $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, and combined with $|x| = -x$ for $x\leq 0$ we have

$-x = \sqrt{y+4}\implies x=-\sqrt{y+4}\implies h^{-1}(x) = -\sqrt{x+4}$

Quick check gives us

$h(h^{-1}(x)) = h(-\sqrt{x+4})= (-\sqrt{x+4})^2 - 4 = x + 4 - 4 = x$

$h^{-1}(h(x)) = h^{-1}(x^2 - 4) = -\sqrt{x^2-4 + 4} = -\sqrt{x^2} = - |x| = x\quad (x\leq 0)$

Comment: Wonderful answer, but I am a little iffy about the statement $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ as $|x|$ indicates a constantly positive root. In the same vein, I feel that a statement like $\sqrt{4} = |\pm2|$ would be wrong.

Comment: @Airdish $\sqrt{}$ is *defined* as the positive value. $x^2 = 4 \implies x = \pm 2$ but $\sqrt{x^2} = 2$.

Comment: @Airdish, this is how square root is defined: "Square root of $a$ is such a _positive_ number which square gives $a$", i.e. square root is a _positive_ solution to equation $x^2 = a$. This is elementary school definition. Formal way is that $x\mapsto x^2\colon [0,\infty\rangle\to [0,\infty\rangle$ is a bijection (note that the domain is not whole $\mathbb R$) and it's inverse is $\sqrt{\ }$, thus by definition $\sqrt x$ is positive. $\sqrt 4 = |\pm 2|$ is absolutely correct, since $\sqrt 4 = 2$, and _not_ $-2$.

Comment: Ah, I've always that the root implied the negative as well as the positive.

Comment: @Airdish, no, that's why you often see something like $x^2 = 4\implies x =\pm\sqrt 4$. Algebraically, there are two solutions, one of them is $\sqrt 4$ and the other is $-\sqrt 4$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose

$$\;x\le 0\;,\;\;y=x^2-4\implies x^2=y+4\implies-x=\sqrt{y+4}\iff x=-\sqrt{y+4}$$

Observe this only applies whenever $\;y\ge-4\;$, which is fine since

$$x\le 0\implies y=x^2-4\ge-4\;,\;\;\text{since}\;\;x^2\ge0$$

So your answer is correct, and perhaps with this explanation now you can justify it better.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main confusion you have is whether you should take the positive or negative function. In this case an easy thing to do would be to visualize the graph. Notice that the graph is U-shaped and you only wish to take the 'left side' of it. And you also know that the inverse is a reflection across $y = x$. Then you have an idea that the reflection of the 'left arm' will be below the x-axis. And so it is $-\sqrt{x + 4}$ instead of the positive.

Furthermore note that in saying $h(a)$ you imply that $a \le 0 $ and it follows that when you take square roots of $a^2 = x + 4$ you need to keep in mind this restriction, so it has to be $-\sqrt{x+ 4}$

Answer (score 0):

$h^{-1}=-\sqrt{x+4}$ but the domain of $h^{-1}$ is the image of $h$, ie, $[-4,+\infty)$.